# How to correctly mock new Date in Vue.js Jest test so snapshots do not fail?

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, jestjs, bootstrap-vue, ts-jest

*The goal is to mock the javascript Date object so that when I run my tests and snapshots are evaluated, the snapshot is not always failing.*

I am attempting to write a Jest test for a function that utilizes the `new Date` constructor in a Vue 2.6.8 app (this is a Typescript project).

I have bound a variable called `maxDate` to the component.  It uses a getter to compute the value as needed.  The goal is to limit the date pickers' selectable range. Here is what the code looks like:

**Vue Template:**

```
<template>
  <date-picker :max-date="maxDate" />
</template>
```

**Vue class method:**

```
private get maxDate() {
  return new Date();
}
```

**Jest Test (to match snapshot):**

```
describe('Snapshots', () => {
  test('snapshot 1', () => {
    expect(component.vm.$el).toMatchSnapshot();
  });
});
```

**The question I have is:** How do I prevent my snapshots from failing since the date is going to change every time I run my tests?

For example, the first time I run the test and the snapshot is generated, I get something like this in the snapshot itself.

**First run (generate snapshot):**

```
...
maxdate="Wed Oct 30 2019 12:27:08 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time)"
...
```

And the next time I run the tests - say exactly one minute later - the snapshot will fail because it will be expecting the previous date but is now getting different data.

**Second run (snapshot fails):**

```
...
maxdate="Wed Oct 30 2019 12:28:08 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time)"
...
```

Comment: Did you get a solution? I have mocked `Date` constructor but in my Vue component computed still gets original `Date` object and fails the test :-/